# How to serve scaled images in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I display the images like:

```
 <img class="card-img-top" style="max-height: 121px; 
 border:1px solid #eee;"
 src="{{ $post->image == null ? url('img/default.png') : url($post->image)}}
```

But in the pagespeed analysis it appears a recommendation "PageSpeed: Serve scaled images" for some images like:

The following images are resized in HTML or CSS. Serving scaled images could save 353.7KiB (90% reduction).

Do you know how to correct this issue?

```
https://....ngrok.io/uploads/posts/img1.png is resized in HTML or CSS from 800x400 to 251x119. Serving a scaled image could save 173.3KiB (90% reduction).
https://....ngrok.io/uploads/posts/img2.jpg is resized in HTML or CSS from 800x400 to 251x119. Serving a scaled image could save 40.2KiB (90% reduction).
https://....ngrok.io/uploads/posts/img3.jpg is resized in HTML or CSS from 800x400 to 251x119. Serving a scaled image could save 38.3KiB (90% reduction).
https://....ngrok.io/uploads/posts/img4.jpg is resized in HTML or CSS from 800x400 to 251x119. Serving a scaled image could save 31.6KiB (90% reduction).
https://...ngrok.io/uploads/posts/img5.jpg is resized in HTML or CSS from 800x400 to 251x119. Serving a scaled image could save 28.9KiB (90% reduction).
https://....ngrok.io/uploads/posts/img6.jpg is resized in HTML or CSS from 800x400 to 251x119. Serving a scaled image could save 28.0KiB (90% reduction).
https://....ngrok.io/uploads/posts/img7.jpg is resized in HTML or CSS from 800x400 to 251x119. Serving a scaled image could save 13.4KiB (90% reduction).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means you must have an image in your server the size of the container you're viewing it in, for example an image on mobile should have a maximum width of `425px`

If the images are static, you could create each image for the container width it is showing in the pageSpeed report.

Otherwise you could use a package like [intervention](http://image.intervention.io/), this package lets you manipulate images as you want, but this means more process on the server side.

Comment: Intervention is definitely the way to go, when people upload a post image you should resize it to 250 px wide if thats the largest you ever need to display it. You can also store two copies at `filename.jpg` and `filename-thumb.jpg` so you can use it both ways.

Answer (score 1):

It means resizing the images to the specs you need using an image editor and uploading them to your website, instead of resize them using css or html.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain that of using an image editor? The image is inserted by the user using a input type file and then is stored in the uploads/posts folder.

Comment: he means like photoshop, illustrator, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> I know this answer is late but for your information I'll update my
>   answer with respect to Laravel.

What I do in this is when user upload a image I do resize it into different sizes. When I upload a image I make it to 500 x 500 image .See the below code I used to resize images

```
if ( request () -> thumbnail )
    {
        $imageName = time () . '.' . request () -> thumbnail -> getClientOriginalExtension () ;

        $path =  ( 'uploads/products/' . $imageName ) ; 
        $path150 =  ( 'uploads/products/150x150/' . $imageName ) ;
        $path250 =  ( 'uploads/products/250x250/' . $imageName ) ; 
        Image::make ( request () -> thumbnail -> getRealPath () ) -> resize ( 150 , 150 ) -> save ( $path150 ) ;  //resize to 150px x 150px
        Image::make ( request () -> thumbnail -> getRealPath () ) -> resize ( 260 , 260 ) -> save ( $path250 ) ;//resize to 250px x 250px
        Image::make ( request () -> thumbnail -> getRealPath () ) -> resize ( 450 , 450 ) -> save ( $path ) ; // original image
        $product -> thumbnail_file_name = $imageName ;
    }
```

To display those images in different locations I make some helper classes to load images as below

```
public function Image250X250()
{
    if ( $this -> thumbnail_file_name )
    {
        $file_path = 'uploads/products/250x250/' . $this -> thumbnail_file_name ;

        if ( File::exists ( $file_path ) )
        {
        return asset ( '/uploads/products/250x250/'  . $this -> thumbnail_file_name );
        }
    }

    return asset ( '/no-preview-250-250.jpg' ) ;
}
```

Then in the view I call those functions to load images as below

```
<div class="col-2">
<img src="{{ $variable -> Image150X150}}"
</div>

<div class="col-4">
<img src="{{ $variable -> Image250X250}}"
</div>
```

As alternative to this you can use `srcset` . Means that this will display the image respect to the your view width. In here you also have to make different type of resolution images and then as below code you can add them to the view.

```
  <picture>
     <source media="(max-width: 575px)" srcset="{{asset('uploads/banners01.jpg')}}">
     <source media="(max-width: 768px)" srcset="{{asset('uploads/banners02.jpg')}}">
     <img class="d-block w-100  lazy img-fluid " height="349" width="960" src="{{asset('uploads/banners_def.jpg')}}" alt="xxxxxxxx">
  </picture>
```

Check this site to generate srcset images with its html code. This makes your process easy

[Responsive Image Breakpoints Generator v2.0](https://www.responsivebreakpoints.com/)